# Android contentResolver.query witth Uri received from Storage Access Framework (SAF)

Tags: android, android-file, android-contentresolver, android-fileprovider, android-storage

Previously I had logic where I located the needed folder on external storage (using my own file chooser which returned a File to chosen folder) and then just queried all the media files in it, using the path as prefix, there is a logic:

```
fun loadAudio(path: String): List<Audio> {

        val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
        val uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

        val projection = arrayOf(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID
        )

        val selection = "${MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC} != 0 AND ${MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA} LIKE '${path}%'"
        val sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC"
        val cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, selection, null, sortOrder)

        val tempAudioList = arrayListOf<Audio>()

        if (cursor != null && cursor.count > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                val data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA))
                val fileName = data.split(File.separator).let { it[it.size - 1] }
                val title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE))
                val album = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM))
                val artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST))
                val duration = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION))
                val albumId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID))

                // Save to audioList
                tempAudioList.add(Audio(data, fileName, title, album, artist, duration, albumId))
            }
        }

        cursor!!.close()
        return tempAudioList
    }
```

Now android deprecates the direct access using File, and we are forced to use Storage Access Framework (SAF).
So I started to use:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
        intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 42)
```

Which returns Uri to the folder.
The problem is that: I no longer have the direct filesystem path to the folder, so when I try to query media files using `contentResolver.query`, I no longer able to write selection like:

```
val selection = "${MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC} != 0 AND ${MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA} LIKE '${path}%'"
```

Because I don't have path anymore.
I switched to use DocumentFile, but when I try to use that Uri in that SQL selection clause, it just doesn't work...
I have 1 workaround like: get the filename from the DocumentFile and then try to use it in query and filter by `${MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME} LIKE ${name}`, but filesystem might have several files with the same name.
Can somebody suggest me the way I should follow, to select the folder (as I do now with SAF and then be able using `contentResolver.query` to query all the audios in that folder get their media tags?

Also if I use Uri of the folder or any of it's subfiles in:

```
contentResolver.query(uri, projection, selection, null, sortOrder)
```

in doesn't return me any media tags

Comment: `Now android deprecates the direct access using File, and we are forced...` No. Set one simple flag in manifest file and an Android 10 device behaves as before. And for Android 11 devices you just have file read access as before.

Comment: `Which returns Uri to the folder. The problem is that: I no longer have the direct filesystem path to the folder, ..` Yes you have. Look closely to the content scheme and you see the folder name. Even full path.

Comment: For querying the media store use column .RELATIVE_PATH instead of .DATA for Android 10+ devices.

Comment: @blackapps 1) yeah, but that flag for manifest will be ignored in future versions, so that is why I decided to reimplement this.
2) Yea I have some path there but it doesnt match the data, I finally implemented it with: 
 val selection1 = "${MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC} != 0 AND ${MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA} LIKE '%${path.parentFile!!.name}${File.separator}${path.name}%'" .
3) Ok, thanks, will take a look on RELATIVE_PATH

Comment: `, but that flag for manifest will be ignored in future versions, so that is why I decided to reimplement this` Yes, it is only for Android 10 devices. And if you had read my first comment you would have know that you need nothing extra for Android 11 devices except using a different column. And very often a different collection.

Comment: With Android 10+ you can let the media store convert a SAF uri to a media uri. Try that.

Comment: @blackapps thanks, I tried to use MediaStore.getMediaUri, it works, but my document uri is always point to a folder, and I need all the audio files in that folder. My app is audio book reader.
So as I understand even if I use MediaStore.getMediaUri to get mediaUri of the folder, I will not be able to use it in the query, so I should go with MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH and folder name in query.